# Any magic formulas for roasting a gammon joint?

Tags: roasting, gammon

wondering if there is a magic formula (i.e weight/temp/time) in order to get a gammon just right?

Comment: Could you help out those of us who have no clue whether a *gammon* is animal, vegetable, or mineral?

Answer (score 1):

Slow cooked, braise, to internal temperature of 160 F plus.  So, covered in the oven, with some liquid.  Treat it like a pork shoulder or a fresh picnic and you should be fine, since most ham recipes (which is what this is, really) assume a ham that is already cooked.